# Link_to using on div instead of text

Tags: html, ruby, bootstrap-4, haml, afas-online

Can I use the link_to clickable for the whole div instead of only clicking on ¨Boeken naar afas¨?

Like at this moment if you click on ¨boeken naar afas¨ then the link_to does something.
I want to have it on the div instead of the text. So when you click on the div then it will be triggerd the ¨update_bookkeeping_claims_claim_manager_path(@claim_manager), method: 'post'¨

```
      .col-sm-6.col-md-5.col-lg-3.item.ibox-title.import{:onclick => "move()"}
        .box.boxBatenmanager
          .boxInsite.boxTop
            %i.fa.fa-exchange.icon.iconApps
            %h3.name
              Baten boeken naar #{@claim_manager.bookkeeping_name || 'AFAS'} do
              %br/
            %h4.description
              Uw heeft #{@claim_manager.claims.scheduled_to_update_bookkeeping.count} baten
              (#{@claim_manager.institution_claim_mutations.scheduled_to_update_bookkeeping.count} mutaties) aangemerkt om te boeken.
              = link_to "Boeken naar AFAS", update_bookkeeping_claims_claim_manager_path(@claim_manager), method: 'post'
              %br/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can pass a block](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) instead of a text label to the `link_to` helper, which allows you to nest your whole markup in the link:

```
= link_to update_bookkeeping_claims_claim_manager_path(@claim_manager), method: 'post' do
  .col-sm-6.col-md-5.col-lg-3.item.ibox-title.import{:onclick => "move()"}
    [...]
```

Comment: I did the same thing and tried other things to like using the =link_to under the .col. Problem was at the end that I had my Tab wrong, which is very sensitive in haml. THanks btw it worked I only had to do this: change the .col with the =link position and had to have the Tabs on the right place :)